# VB.Net "Index was outside the bounds of the array." when trying to increment Array element

Tags: arrays, vb.net, record

I have an array of records, defined like this:

```
Structure TNumTemp
        Dim BKA As String
        Dim Num As Integer
        Dim Name As String
    End Structure
 Dim Tarray(LOF(2) / Len(LocationRecord) - 1) As TNumTemp
```

When I try to increment Tarray(i).Num using **Tarray(i).Num = Tarray(i).Num + 1** I get the error mentioned in the title for some reason! Here is relevant code:

```
For i = 1 To LOF(2) / Len(LocationRecord)
            FileGet(2, LocationRecord, i)

            Tarray(i - 1).Name = Trim(LocationRecord.LocationName)
            Tarray(i - 1).Num = 0
            For j = 1 To LOF(3) / Len(TournamentRecord)
                FileGet(3, TournamentRecord, j)
                If Trim(TournamentRecord.LocationName) = Trim(Tarray(i - 1).Name) Then
                    Tarray(i).Num = Tarray(i).Num + 1
                End If
            Next
        Next
```

From my understanding, by the array's bounds it means the number of elements in the array? But it is assigning an element of the array, but an element of one of the structures!?

Comment: When the exception is thrown, what is the size of the array and what is the index being accessed?  The runtime is telling you that those numbers don't match, and it's usually right about that sort of thing.

Comment: The errors says it all, now you need to debug to find why exactly you get out of bounds.

Comment: `From my understanding, by the array's bounds it means the number of elements in the array` - this is how it is in C++. In VB.NET you provide the upper bound (with the lower bound implicitly being `0`), so you get one more elements in the array than the number you requested. You request `Tarray(0 To NumRecords - 1)`, then you iterate it `From 1 To NumRecords`.

Comment: My crystal ball says that you must update Tarray(i - 1).Num.  Maybe it is a good idea to get used to the idea that computers start counting at 0, you'll have fewer off-by-one bugs that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared your array to have elements with indexes 0 through (LOF(2) / Len(LocationRecord) - 1). The most common way to loop through all index values would be to code

```
For i = 0 To LOF(2) / Len(LocationRecord) - 1
```

But you coded

```
For i = 1 To LOF(2) / Len(LocationRecord)
```

In most cases, you compensated for that by using (i-1) instead of (i) as the array index inside the loop, but in the statement that is getting the error you did not. The last time round the loop, i will be (LOF(2) / Len(LocationRecord)) which is one more than the last array index. You need to change the problem statement to

```
Tarray(i - 1).Num = Tarray(i - 1).Num + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You created an array of n-1 length

```
Dim arr(n - 1) As Integer
```

But you loop until n

```
arr(n) = 10 ' This will not work because you are above the array length
```

Remove the -1 when initializing your array. Or loop until the end of the array

```
For i = 1 To Tarray.Length-1
```